# Is there a way to add all elements in an iterable of iterables to a list without a for loop in Python?

Tags: python, list, iterable

Is there a more Pythonic way (that is, in one line, without a loop, and without the trivial initialization) of computing the list `all` below?

```
all = []
for iterable in iterables:
    all.extend(iterable)  # add all elements in 'iterable' to 'all'
```

Edit: it is ok if the solution takes linear time. I just want a more readable, shorter, direct way of doing it.

Comment: you want to move every element from elements WITHOUT USING A LOOP to a list (flatten the structure).. which may be possible for some data structures that are sequentially stored in memory, but not universally.

Comment: Is the question about if it's possible to do the operation in constant time vs linear? If so, then the answer is "in some cases its possible"

Comment: No, I don't mean constant time, I just mean a more sucinct, readable way. It can still be linear time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from itertools import chain

result = list(chain(*iterables))
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain

It's like hiding the loop... no different

Answer (score -1):

```
all = [iterable for iterable in iterables]
```

You can also just copy to the other one like below

```
all = all + iterables
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not produce the same result as my example. My example produces a flat list, while this produces a list of lists. Perhaps you read 'extend' as 'append'.

Comment: No this does not produces a list of lists. It produces a flat list. 

    >>> a = [1,2,3,4] 
    >>> t = []  
    >>> t = [ai for ai in a]
    >>> t
    [1, 2, 3, 4]

Comment: Sorry, I don't see what you mean. Any list comprehension of the form `[x for x in xs]` is equal to `xs`, right? So `[iterable for iterable in iterables]` is the same as `iterables`. If `iterables` is, for example, a list of lists, then it is not flat. Also, I tested your solution and confirmed my conclusion: `iterables = [[1,2,3], [10,20]]
all = [iterable for iterable in iterables]`, then we see `all` to be `[[1, 2, 3], [10, 20]]`. My example produces `[1, 2, 3, 10, 20]`.

Comment: Ok i was confused with the input `iterables = [[1,2,3], [10,20]]` and i thought the input will be [1,2,3,4] like this. My bad. :)